# Como obtener el array en reduce?

Tags: javascript

Quiero obtener el array con el menor resultado al multiplicar todos sus terminos.

Los array estaran dentro de otro array, para trabajar con ellos.

Mi codigo es:

```js
function _min (arr){
 var _reduced = arr.map(cur => {
   return cur.reduce((c,i)=> {
   return c * i;
   });
 });
 return Math.min(..._reduced);
}
console.log(_min([[4,3,5],[5,2,5]]));
```

Obtengo correctamente los valores, pero como podria obtener a que array **pertenece** el menor valor obtenido ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

También puedes hacer que la propia función `_min` te devuelva toda la información.

En este ejemplo `_min` devuelve un objeto con el valor del producto, el propio array y el índice del array:

```js
function _min (arr){
  return arr.reduce(
    (prev, item, index) => {
      var prod = item.reduce((p, c) => p * c);
      return prev == null || prev.value > prod
        ? { value: prod, arr: item, index: index }
        : prev;
    }, null);
}

console.log(_min([[4,3,5],[5,2,5]]));
```

En el array interno se utiliza `reduce` para hacer el cálculo del producto (tal y como lo hacías en el ejemplo). Los parámetros `p` y `c` se corresponden con los elementos "anterior" y "actual" en cada iteración. Al no dar un valor inicial al valor "anterior" en la primera iteración `p` se corresponderá con el primer elemento del array y `c` con el segundo. A partir de la segunda iteración `p` tiene el valor calculado hasta el momento y `c` el elemento actual.

El `reduce` externo aplica al array completo (el array de arrays) y va recorriendo cada elemento para quedarse con el de producto menor. En este caso el valor "anterior" se inicializa con `null` por lo que en la primera iteración `prev` tiene un valor de `null`, `item` (elemento "actual") se corresponde con el primer array e `index` será 0 (índice del primer elemento).

Para entender bien el ejemplo hay que comprender cómo funciona el método `reduce` del objeto `Array`. Voy a tratar de aclararlo con algunos ejemplos.

**El método `reduce`**

El primer problema a la hora de entender el comportamiento del método `reduce` suele venir a raíz del nombre que se le suele dar a los dos primeros parámetros que recibe la función que se pasa al método: "anterior" y "actual". Estos nombres pueden dar la impresión de que se trata de elementos del mismo tipo (como el elemento anterior y actual del array) cuando no es así.

"anterior" hace referencia al valor devuelto por la iteración anterior: el resultado obtenido hasta el momento.

"actual" hace referencia al elemento actual del array que se está tratando en la iteración.

Para tratar de evitar esta confusión a partir de ahora me referiré a ese primer parámetro ("anterior") como "resultado" o "resultado calculado".

La otra fuente de confusiones suele ser los dos modos de comportamiento que tiene el método en función de si se  provee un valor con el que inicializar el "resultado" o no.

El modo normal de comportamiento del método `reduce` es en el que se le pasa la función a ejecutar en cada iteración y un valor con el que inicializar el "resultado". De esta forma el método ejecuta la función para cada elemento del array. En la primera iteración el parámetro "resultado calculado" contiene el valor de inicialización, en las siguientes iteraciones este parámetro contiene el valor devuelto por la anterior iteración. De esta forma (siguiendo el ejemplo de arriba) para calcular el producto de todos los elementos del array haríamos:

```js
var arr = [4,3,5];

var final = arr.reduce(function(result, current, index){
  console.log('***** Iteración ' + index + '\n',
    'Resultado anterior: ' + result,
    'Valor actual: ' + current,
    'Valor a devolver: ' + result * current);
  return result * current;
}, 1);

console.log('**** Resultado final: ' + final);
```

El segundo método de funcionamiento se utiliza cuando el resultado de la primera iteración es siempre el primer elemento del array. En el caso anterior, por ejemplo, en la primera iteración siempre se devuelve el primer elemento por el valor de inicialización (que es `1`), es decir, el primer elemento.

En estos casos se puede omitir el valor de inicialización para el "resultado". El método `reduce` entonces comienza la iteración por el segundo elemento del array, pasándole como "resultado calculado" el primer elemento:

```js
var arr = [4,3,5];

var final = arr.reduce(function(result, current, index){
  console.log('***** Iteración ' + index + '\n',
    'Resultado anterior: ' + result,
    'Valor actual: ' + current,
    'Valor a devolver: ' + result * current);
  return result * current;
});

console.log('**** Resultado final: ' + final);
```

Como se puede ver el primer "elemento actual" es el `3` (segundo elemento del array) y el "resultado anterior" que se pasa a esa primera iteración es el `4` primer elemento.

Aunque el resultado obtenido es el mismo, hay que tener en cuenta un par de diferencias:

1. Se realiza una iteración menos, por lo que cualquier tipo de procesamiento adicional que se realice en la función no se realizará para el primer elemento. En nuestro ejemplo la salida a consola es diferente. En un caso real si, por ejemplo, en la función aprovechamos para validar los elementos del array, esa validación no se realizará para el primer elemento.
2. Si el array está vacío y no se proporciona un valor de inicialización para el resultado el método `reduce` da error:

```js
var arr = [];

var final = arr.reduce(function(result, current, index){
  console.log('***** Iteración ' + index + '\n',
    'Resultado anterior: ' + result,
    'Valor actual: ' + current,
    'Valor a devolver: ' + result * current);
  return result * current;
}, 1);

console.log('**** Resultado final: ' + final);

final = arr.reduce(function(result, current, index){
  console.log('***** Iteración ' + index + '\n',
    'Resultado anterior: ' + result,
    'Valor actual: ' + current,
    'Valor a devolver: ' + result * current);
  return result * current;
});

console.log('**** Resultado final: ' + final);
```

El mismo sistema podemos utilizar para, por ejemplo, obtener valores mínimos y máximos de un array:

```js
var arr = [4, 18, 21, 5, 3, 17, 25, 1, 3, 18, 2];

// Calcular valor mínimo
var final = arr.reduce(function(result, current, index){
  console.log('***** Iteración ' + index + '\n',
    'Resultado anterior: ' + result,
    'Valor actual: ' + current,
    'Valor a devolver: ' + Math.min(result==null? current : result, current));
  return Math.min(result==null? current : result, current);  
}, null);

console.log('**** Resultado final: ' + final);

final = arr.reduce(function(result, current, index){
  console.log('***** Iteración ' + index + '\n',
    'Resultado anterior: ' + result,
    'Valor actual: ' + current,
    'Valor a devolver: ' + Math.min(result, current));
  return Math.min(result, current);  
});

console.log('**** Resultado final: ' + final);
```

Podríamos hacer también que el "resultado" fuera, por ejemplo, los dos números menores. Para ello el resultado debería ser un objeto con dos propiedades: "minor" y "second". En este caso el primer valor del array no nos sirve como "resultado anterior" para la segunda iteración por lo que deberíamos utilizar el modo con valor de inicialización.

Lo que haré es dar un valor de inicialización con un objeto con las dos propiedades con valor `Infinity` de esta forma todos los elementos del array serán menores que esos valores:

```js
var arr = [4, 18, 21, 5, 3, 17, 25, 1, 3, 18, 2];

// Esta función es simplemente para convertir a string el resultado
// y poder mostrarlo en consola
function serialize(resultObject){
  return '{ minor: ' + resultObject.minor
    + ' second: ' + resultObject.second + ' }';
}

// Calcular los dos valores menores
var final = arr.reduce(function(result, current, index){
  console.log('***** Iteración ' + index + '\n',
    'Resultado anterior: ' + serialize(result),
    'Valor actual: ' + current);
  if (current < result.minor){
    // El actual es menor: el menor actual pasa a segundo menor
    result.second = result.minor;
    result.minor = current;
  }
  else if(current < result.second){
    // El actual es menor que el segundo menor
    result.second = current;
  }
  console.log('Valor a devolver: ' + serialize(result));
  return result;  
}, {minor: Infinity, second: Infinity});

console.log('**** Resultado final: ' + serialize(final));
```

Comment: Tengo dudas, cómo, porqué usas doble reduce ? si este tiene como parámetros el elemento anterior y el actual, entonces solo te "recorrera" por uno de los dos y no por todos los elementos ? y si no es así, a cual se le aplica el segundo reduce ? al anterior o al actual ? y por qué? , además porqué le asignas null como valor inicial ? y porque se lo asignas al primer reduce y no al segundo ?

Comment: Muchas dudas. Edito y trato de aclararlo.

Comment: Me has aclarado, pero cuál es la lógica al comparar los valores y al asignar un objeto ? Cómo es posible que me devuelva toda la información? me intriga muchísimo tu solución

Comment: Cuando haces la verificacion de si es null, para que ? y el prev.value > prod es para saber si el elemento anterior es mayor, y en ese caso retornara nuevos valores en el objeto ? y si no es mayor, retorna el mismo ?

Comment: Si es `null` quiere decir que se está tratando el primer elemento del array y por tanto el valor no se puede comparar con ningún valor anterior. Si no es `null` es que ya hay un valor anterior con el que comparar, si el nuevo valor es menor se devuelve el nuevo, si no se devuelve el calculado anteriormente. Voy a editar la respuesta para tratar de aclararlo más.

Answer (score 3):

A partir del `return` de tu código...

Aquí devuelves **el resultado** del *Array* que tiene el mínimo resultado:

```
return Math.min(..._reduced);                         // => 50
```

Acá devuelves **la posición** del *Array* que tiene el mínimo resultado:

```
return _reduced.indexOf(Math.min(..._reduced));       // => 1
```

Acá devuelves **el *Array*** que tiene el mínimo resultado:

```
return arr[_reduced.indexOf(Math.min(..._reduced))];  // => [5, 2, 5]
```

---

**Explicación del procedimiento de tu código:** (Por tu pregunta en el comentario de esta respuesta)

**Problema:** Quiero obtener el array con el menor resultado al multiplicar todos sus terminos.

Tu código es:

```
function _min (arr){
 var _reduced = arr.map(cur => {
   return cur.reduce((c,i)=> {
   return c * i;
   });
 });
 // return de acuerdo a lo que quieres.
}
```

Lo primero que estás haciendo dentro de esta función (`_min`), es generar un **nuevo array** (con `map`) a partir de *otro* (desde `arr`), y a ese nuevo array resultante guardarlo en una variable (`_reduced`).

```
arr.map(
  cur => cur.reduce(
    (c,i) => c * i
  )
);
```

*Nota: Reacomodé tu código para que la presentación sea más clara, pero es exactamente el mismo código.*

1. En detalle; si la entrada es `[ [4,3,5], [5,2,5] ]`, ver que es un *array* que contiene **dos** *arrays*, entonces, primer paso:

   `[ [4,3,5], [5,2,5] ].map(cur => "cuerpo de la funcion")`

El `map` significa que por **cada** elemento del *array*, vas a aplicar la función que colocas dentro de los paréntesis. El array que recibe el map, es el que tiene como **primer elemento** a `[4,3,5]` y como **segundo elemento** a `[5,2,5]`. No confundir.

Tu variable `cur`, es el nombre temporal que tendrá cada uno de los elementos. Como son solamente 2, entonces tendrás 2 iteraciones. En la **primera iteración** `cur = [4,3,5]` y en la **segunda iteración** `cur = [5,2,5]`.

2. Segundo paso, la función que vas a aplicar a *cada array*, es esta:

   `cur => cur.reduce("otra funcion")`

A *cada array*, ahora le realizas `reduce`. Lo que hace es **convertir *un* array a *un* único valor**. Tu código quedaría desarrollado así:

```
[4, 3, 5].reduce((c, i) => "cuerpo de la otra función")
[5, 2, 5].reduce((c, i) => "cuerpo de la otra función")
```

Para esto, *por cada elemento de cada array*, ejecuta una función. Esta función tiene dos parámetros. El primero es `c`, que durante la primera iteración tomará el valor del primer elemento, durante las siguientes, tomará el valor del resultado anterior. El segundo parámetro es `i`, que durante la primera iteración tomará el valor del segundo elemento, y en las siguientes el siguiente elemento entre los restantes...

Si no entendiste lo de arriba, explico con el ejemplo para que sea más claro. Luego puedes releer el párrafo anterior cuando entiendas el ejemplo:

```
[4, 3, 5].reduce((c, i) => c * i)

// Primera iteración: c = 4  (primer elemento), i = 3 (segundo elemento). 
  // c * i es entonces 4 * 3 = 12. Este es el primer resultado.
// Segunda iteración: c = 12 (tu primer resultado), i = 5 (tercer elemento).
  // c * i es entonces 12 * 5 = 60
// No quedan más elementos en el array, así que devuelve el último resultado: 60.
```

Lo mismo sucede con el otro array de `[5, 2, 5]`:

```
[5, 2, 5].reduce((c, i) => c * i)

// Primera iteración: c = 5, i = 2. 
  // 5 * 2 = 10. 
// Segunda iteración: c = 10, i = 5
  // 10 * 5 = 50
// No quedan más elementos en el array, así que devuelve el último resultado: 50.
```

Una vez entendido lo anterior, hay que recordar de dónde venía todo:

```
[4,3,5].reduce((c, i) => c * i) // => 60
[5,2,5].reduce((c, i) => c * i) // => 50
```

Que a su vez, era una función que venía dentro de un `map`:

```
let _reduced = arr.map(cur => cur.reduce((c, i) => c * i)) // => [60, 50]
```

Entonces en tu variable `_reduced` cuentas con tu **nuevo array**, que es `[60, 50]`. Este nuevo array, es *paralelo* al array de entrada, `arr`.

```
[[4,3,5],[5,2,5]]  // Array de entrada arr
[  60   ,   50  ]  // Array en _reduced
```

Por lo tanto, el *índice* de uno de los arrays, se corresponde con el índice del otro. `60` se corresponde con `[4,3,5]`, y `50` se corresponde con `[5,2,5]`.

Por último, ¿cual es la solución que quieres devolver? Antes lo que devolvías era:

```
return Math.min(..._reduced);
```

Que se resuelve como:

```
return Math.min(...[60, 50]); // Continuando a:
return Math.min(60, 50);      // Y el mínimo acá, es el 50 que devolvías.
```

Tu duda al respecto, es **¿Por qué *indexOf* de 50 devuelve 1, que es la posición del array que buscabas?** Ahora queda más claro, pero si no... El desarrollo de cómo se iría interpretando:

```
return _reduced.indexOf(Math.min(..._reduced)); // indexOf de _reduced, no de arr.      
return [60, 50].indexOf(Math.min(...[60, 50]));
return [60, 50].indexOf(Math.min(60, 50));
return [60, 50].indexOf(50); // En qué posición está el 50? => 1
```

Por último, si quieres obtener el array que contiene el mínimo resultado. Como ambos arrays `_reduced` y `arr` **son paralelos**, entonces:

```
return arr[_reduced.indexOf(Math.min(..._reduced))];
return arr[[60, 50].indexOf(Math.min(60, 50))];       
return arr[1];                   // arr es [[4,3,5],[5,2,5]], por lo tanto:
return [ [4,3,5], [5,2,5] ] [1]; // En la posición 1, está [5,2,5]
return [5,2,5];
```

Puedes realizar el mismo desarrollo para cualquier entrada que pases. Y te recomiendo que si estás aprendiendo, intentes ejecutar el código en cada paso que hagas, así puedes ir viendo este desarrollo de una forma más divertida y clara :)

Comment: Cómo es posible que indexOf the devuelve un índice, si ningú array tiene "50" en sus valores ?

Comment: Ahí edité la respuesta con la explicación completa de todo el algoritmo y por qué los diferentes returns. Cualquier duda, pregunta :)

Answer (score 1):

> Quiero obtener el array con el menor resultado al multiplicar todos sus terminos.

Entonces podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Creamos un objeto contra el cual vamos a comparar todos los valores del arreglo (`eg: {v: Infinity, a: null}`)
- Para cada valor del arreglo:

  - Calculamos su producto (`eg: item.reduce((v, n) => {return v * n}`)
  - Creamos un objeto donde guardamos el producto y el arreglo (`eg: let next = {a: item, v: item.reduce...`)
  - Y lo comparamos contra el del objeto inicial y conservamos el que sea menor (`eg: return next.v < prev.v ? next : prev;`)
- Al finalizar devolvemos el arreglo del objeto cuyo valor sea menor al de todos (`eg: return arr.reduce(...).a;`).

### Demo

```js
function _min(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((prev, item) => {
    let next = {a: item, v: item.reduce((v, n) => {return v * n})};
    return next.v < prev.v ? next : prev;
  }, {v: Infinity, a: null}).a;
}

console.log(_min([
  [4, 3, 5],
  [5, 2, 5]
]));
```

Comment: Tengo muchas dudas, por qué usas doble reduce ? ,  reduce tendrá el elemento anterior y el actual, por lo cual en el segundo reduce se lo aplicaras al anterior o al actual , además uno necesita aplicarselo a todos , no ? Por qué le asignas un valor inicial a reduce y por qué lo comparas  y para qué?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian, el primer reduce, es para obtener **1 solo resultado**, y ese seria el *arreglo cuyo valor sea el menor de todos*. El segundo reduce es para obtener el producto de los valores dentro de cada arreglo. El objeto inicial es para poder compara el valor del primer arreglo contra un número muy grande (`eg: Inifity`) y no tener que controlar si `prev` no es `null` para poder comparar.

Comment: Como sabes cual es el de menor valor , en el primer reduce, si en el segundo lo calculas ?